# How do Exotic Bounties work?

Tags: destiny

I have stumbled upon an exotic bounty while playing Destiny....I did this after turning in various other bounties, both Vanguard and Crucible.... Does anyone know how these exotic bounties actually spawn? Like is there a specific number of bounties needed to be completed, or is it just luck based?

Just an FYI exotic bounties give you an exotic piece of equipment after completing various challenges...

Comment: Title is really generic, try to extend it.

Comment: Thanks for editing it I guess. Not exactly what I was thinking but it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are completely random. Typically they are offered when turning in other bounties. To increase your chances, keep up with your bounties!

[Here](http://www.reddit.com/r/DestinyTheGame/comments/2gd6on/exotic_bounties_how_are_they_triggered/) is a reddit discussion about it.  Not a perfect source, but there seems to be no indication that they are trigged by something specific.

Comment: Will wait a bit on the answer. Give others a chance too.

Answer (score -1):

Its every 30th bounty that you receive an exotic bounty.

Comment: I have done 40+ and not received any exotic bounties. Can you verify this?

Comment: yeah I can doubt this one too, I have gotten 2 in one day...there are not 60 bounties in a day lol